# nedb with electron and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, requirejs, electron, nedb

I am working with the electron and nedb, but I am facing some error 
here is my code

```
var DataStore = requireNode('nedb');
var db = new DataStore({ filename: __dirname + '/db.json', autoload: true });
// here i am getting error : TypeError: async.queue is not a function
```

anyone have any idea

there is same question asked by someone but there is no answer
[same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016197/electron-nedb-getting-error-async-queue-is-not-a-function)

and here is my full factory

```
define(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    // handles local dtabase
    var bootstrap = function Initialize(app) {

                var DataStore = requireNode('nedb');
                var db = new DataStore({ filename: __dirname + '/db.json', autoload: true });
        app.factory('repositoryService',[
            function () {


                var factory = {};

                factory.initialize = function () {

                };

                return factory;
            }
        ]);
    }
    return bootstrap;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the async module didn't load correctly: The async.queue function is not defined. It is defined in line 673 of the file node_modules/nedb/node_modules/async/lib/async.js

```
nedb/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:
671      };
672  
673:     async.queue = function (worker, concurrency) {
674          if (concurrency === undefined) {
675              concurrency = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code:

```
var Datastore = require('nedb')
            , db = new Datastore({ filename: 'db/yourdb.json', autoload: true });

        //your promisse    
        activate().then(function(response){
            $scope.data = response;
        });

        /**
         * Your function.
         */
        function activate() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            db.find({}, function(err, newDoc) {
                deferred.resolve(newDoc);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Does it at least create the `db.json`?

Then it should work if you wrap the first code snippet in a controller and load it in a div.